# how to query a specific data field from a document in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve a field from my firestore database. The field name in the database is 'dob'. Here's the code for it

```
   FirebaseUser currentUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCurrentUser();
  }

  void _loadCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() { // call setState to rebuild the view
        this.currentUser = user;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<String> email() async {

    if (currentUser != null) {
      String d;
      var usId = currentUser.uid;
      await Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(usId).get().then((data){
        d = (data.data['dob'].toString());  
      });
      return d;
    } else {
      return "no current user";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var d = email();
    return Container(
      child: Text('$d'??'no'),
    );
  }
}
```

After retrieving the data, I'm trying to display it in a Text Widget. But the only thing the Text widget is displaying

```
Instance of a Future<String>
```

instead of the dob. I am not able to find what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email()` returns a `Future` of type `String`, you can try the following:

```
 FirebaseUser currentUser;
 String emailResult;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCurrentUser();
  }

  void _loadCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      email(user).then((String result) {
      setState(() { // call setState to rebuild the view
        this.currentUser = user;
        this.emailResult = result;
       });
      });
    });
  }

  Future<String> email(user) async {
    if (user != null) {
      await Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(user.uid).get().then((data){
        d = (data.data['dob'].toString());  
      });
      return d;
    } else {
      return "no current user";
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('$emailResult'??'no'),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the `_loadCurrentUser` method call the method `email()` and pass `user` as a parameter, then inside `setState()` assign `result` to `this.emailResult` so you can update the state and then assign `emailResult` to the `Text()` widget.